# Get Programmatically Product Attribute Options Values

Tags: magento2

I would like to get options values from my own product attribute. "Catalog input type for Store Owner" of that attribute is Dropdown. For every option we have three values "Is Default", "Admin", "Default Store View"

I tried this code:

```
//eavConfig is \Magento\Eav\Model\Config class
$attribute = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'designer_id');
$options = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions();
var_dump($options);
```

When I var_dump($options) I can see array of options with values "value" and "label", where "value" is option_id and "label" is "Default Store View" field value.

How to get all fields ("Is Default", "Admin", "Default Store View") values ?

Answer (score 3):

**In Magento1:**

Use [store emulation](http://inchoo.net/magento/emulate-store-in-magento/) to get admin store label.

**In Magento2:**

Default Store View

```
$formOptions = $this->productAttributeRepository->get('attribute')->getOptions();
foreach ($formOptions as $formOption) {
    $name = $formOption->getLabel();
}
```

Admin:

```
 $this->storeManager->setCurrentStore('admin');
 // same code
```

Is Default:

```
 // same code
 $formOption->getIsDefault();
```

Comment: @LordHansolo does it answer your question?

Comment: It does not seem very wise setting the entire store to admin for the sake of getting an attribute label.